# read String data to an arduino from a header file (waveshare Eink)

Tags: string, arduino, header-files, e-ink

Geetings, Im trying to read String files to an arduino from a header file (.h). Its compiling fine but i cant call the string.  When I serial print the string only gibberish shows up on the monitor.
This is my arduino Code:

```
#include <epd4in2.h>
#include <epdif.h>
#include <epdpaint.h>
#include <fonts.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include "epd4in2.h"
#include "imagedata.h"
#include "epdpaint.h"

#include "list.h"

#define COLORED     0
#define UNCOLORED   1

String test1;
String test2;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("port test");

  Epd epd;

  if (epd.Init() != 0) {
    Serial.println("e-Paper init failed");
    return;
  }

  test1 = String(DATA_1[0]);\
  Serial.println(test1);
  test2 = String(DATA_1[1]);
  Serial.println(test2);

  /* This clears the SRAM of the e-paper display */
  epd.ClearFrame();

 /* Due to RAM not enough in Arduino UNO, a frame buffer is not allowed. */
 unsigned char image[1500];
 Paint paint(image, 400, 28);    //width should be the multiple of 8 

 paint.Clear(UNCOLORED);
 paint.DrawStringAt(0, 0, "test1", &Font24, COLORED);
 epd.SetPartialWindow(paint.GetImage(), 100, 40, paint.GetWidth(), 
 paint.GetHeight());

 paint.Clear(COLORED);
 paint.DrawStringAt(100, 2, "test2", &Font24, UNCOLORED);
 epd.SetPartialWindow(paint.GetImage(), 0, 64, paint.GetWidth(), 
 paint.GetHeight());

 /* This displays the data from the SRAM in e-Paper module */
 epd.DisplayFrame();

 /* Deep sleep */
 epd.Sleep();
 }

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

and here the data in the .h file:

```
extern const String DATA_1[] PROGMEM = { "bat", "2244"}; 
extern const String DATA_2[] PROGMEM = { "bmp", "15662"}; 
extern const String DATA_3[] PROGMEM = { "docx", "16670"}; 
extern const String DATA_4[] PROGMEM = { "jpg", "150645"}; 
extern const String DATA_5[] PROGMEM = { "mp3", "9882324"}; 
extern const String DATA_6[] PROGMEM = { "txt", "807"}; 
extern const String DATA_7[] PROGMEM = { "url", "118"};
```

I created this list using a .bat script.

Im pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated.
Kind Regards Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use PROGMEM, the initialised value is stored in the program memory, and a pointer to the location is given to the variable.

But when you use

```
test1 = String(DATA_1[0]);
```

the code searches with the same address in the ram and not the program memory.

You can read about it here.
https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/pgmspace.html

I have faced the same problem before, but I was storing bytes, not strings. So I was able to get away with using pgm_read_byte.
You may have to put in some effort to make the program work.

I hope this helps and Good luck.